# Как сравнить значения в двух разных DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe

Есть 2 подобных датафрейма:

```
  address_id   cluster_id   received     sent
0  71413451        1.0      0.010036    0.000000
1  71413451        1.0      0.000000    0.010038
2  71411914        1.0      0.012594    0.000000
3  71411914        1.0      0.000000    0.012594
4  71410369        1.0      0.210090    0.000000

address_id  cluster_id  received    sent
    57046334    2.0    0.011760    0.00000
    57046334    2.0    0.010038    0.00000
    57046334    2.0    0.000000    0.01176
    57046334    2.0    0.012594    0.02345
```

На выходе массив `[0.010038,0.012594,..]`. Если `0`, то ничего не пишем.

с различными значениями `cluster_id`. Мне нужно получить массив, где будут значения `df1.sent` если `df1['cluster_id'==1][sent] == df2['cluster_id'==2][received]`. То есть, если для какого то `address_id` из `cluster_id=1` значение в столбце `sent` совпадает с `cluster_id=2` значением в столбце `received`, берем значение `sent`.

Как это провернуть?

Comment: Можете привести пример второго DataFrame и пример выходного массива?

Comment: Все исправил! жду...

Comment: покажите что вы ожидаете получить на выходе? И как быть когда `sent` в `df1` и `received` в `df2` нулевые? `address_id` - должен совпадать?

Comment: Добавил. Номера совпадать не должны, но если 1 sent == received, мы его пользуем и выбрасываем

Comment: Добавил ответ...

Comment: ["Что делать с ответами на вопрос?"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 3):

```
res = (df1.query("cluster_id==1 and sent!=0")
          .merge(df2.query("cluster_id==2 and received!=0")[['received']],
                 left_on='sent', right_on='received')
          ['sent']
          .tolist())
```

результат:

```
print(res)
#[0.010038, 0.012594]
```

Пошагово:

```
In [164]: df1.query("cluster_id==1 and sent!=0")
Out[164]:
   address_id  cluster_id  received      sent
1    71413451         1.0       0.0  0.010038
3    71411914         1.0       0.0  0.012594

In [165]: df2.query("cluster_id==2 and received!=0")
Out[165]:
   address_id  cluster_id  received     sent
0    57046334         2.0  0.011760  0.00000
1    57046334         2.0  0.010038  0.00000
3    57046334         2.0  0.012594  0.02345

In [166]: df2.query("cluster_id==2 and received!=0")[['received']]
Out[166]:
   received
0  0.011760
1  0.010038
3  0.012594

In [167]: (df1.query("cluster_id==1 and sent!=0")
     ...:     .merge(df2.query("cluster_id==2 and received!=0")[['received']],
     ...:            left_on='sent', right_on='received'))
Out[167]:
   address_id  cluster_id  received_x      sent  received_y
0    71413451         1.0         0.0  0.010038    0.010038
1    71411914         1.0         0.0  0.012594    0.012594

In [168]: (df1.query("cluster_id==1 and sent!=0")
     ...:     .merge(df2.query("cluster_id==2 and received!=0")[['received']],
     ...:            left_on='sent', right_on='received')
     ...:     ['sent'])
     ...:
Out[168]:
0    0.010038
1    0.012594
Name: sent, dtype: float64
```